# Newton polynomial interpolation degree

Tags: interpolation, computational-mathematics

> It is asked to find a polynomial of adequate degree to estimate $\sqrt{1.035}$. The following table is given:
>   [image: Table]

We know that 1.03 and 1.04 need to be used. From the divided differences table, we see that they are increasing, and we also have some zeros in the second-order divided differences.

I don't get what the author means by "adequate degree". For example, if we start in 1.02, we only can interpolate by a line. But I cannot decide if I should start in 1.01 or 1.

Comment: I think you should construct the polynomial for all the points. Then the result will be most accurate.

Comment: I agree in this point, but in other exercises, since the second divided differences were almost constant (considering they were using only 2 decimals for f(x)) to construct a polynomial of degree 2. But, in this case, the divided diferences value are growing!

Answer (score 2):

The first order differences are almost constant here, they decrease very slowly. The simple linear interpolation between $1.03$ and $1.04$ is appropriate. It gives 
$$
\sqrt{1.035}\approx \frac{1.0149+1.0198}{2} = 1.01735
$$

---

Comparing this to $\sqrt{1.035} =  1.017349497\ldots$ confirms there is no need for higher order interpolation. The result has as many correct significant digits as the input $1.035$.

Another sign that higher degrees are not useful: [quadratic interpolation](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=interpolating%20polynomial%20%7B%7B1.02%2C1.01%7D%2C%7B1.03%2C1.0149%7D%2C%7B1.04%2C1.0198%7D%7D) gives a polynomial with leading coefficient about $10^{-12}$.